# CakePHP: CakeTime i18nFormat for date and time

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization

I'm using the CakeTime class for my localization of dates & times.

For dates it works like I want it to:

```
$timestring = $this->Time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
echo 'DateTime: '.$this->Time->i18nFormat($timestring);

// Result => DateTime: 11/08/2013
```

I want it to also display the time.
For example in the US they use AM/PM and in other places they use the 24 hour notation.

I've looked but can't seem to find a way to do this.

Any idea's?

Edit*
To be clear, the localization works perfectly for the dates(have the LC_TIME files), but the i18nFormat function only returns the date, and from what i saw, passing a format will use that format, not the localized one, example MM/DD/YYYY vs DD.MM.YYYY in a different locale

*Edit2: 
The solution vicocamacho gave in the comments is the correct one
So to get the Date + Time in the localized form:

```
$this->Time->i18nFormat(time(), '%x %X') does the trick!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [TimeHelper::i18nFormat](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-TimeHelper.html#_i18nFormat) method. You also can check this repo to find common date/time translations https://github.com/cakephp/localized be sure to store them in the `APP/locale/<locale>/LC_TIME`directory

Comment: I have the LC_TIME files, copied them from /usr/share/i18n/locales/,the problem i'm facing is i want to display the time as well. the i18nFormat function only returns the date and works great.

If i pass a format to the i18nFormat function, will it still use the format from the LC_TIME file? from what I saw not. So then it's not localized anymore. Example in the use it's MM/DD/YYYY and somewhere else it's DD.MM.YYYY. Is cake smart enough to modify it even if i pass a fixed format?

Comment: I investigated a little more and found this, you can do `$this->Time->i18nFormat(time(), '%x %X')` this will output the date and time based on locale, maybe that will do the trick

Comment: I've updated the OP to reflect your solution, works like a charm